# Unity 3d, sphere transform into cube when I tap on screen

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've tried to create a simple script to exercise with unity 3d, but I have this problem.
On the **void start** I create a simple 3d sphere, and when I click on the screen, the sphere 
 should transform in a another object (for example a cube). I've tried to create a **Empty Game Object** and create this script for change the object, but with the empty object I can't use the Rigidbody for the spawned 3d Objects. How could I solve this problem?

I would like for the sphere to switch into a cube when I click the screen.

Maybe should I add a rigidbody into a this script?

this is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class creatorscriptFunzionante : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int counter; //contatore per le forme da spawnare

    //forme da spawnare
    public GameObject sphereBase; //sfera iniziale
    public GameObject sphere;
    public GameObject cube;
    public GameObject capsule;

    private void Awake()
    {

    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {


            counter++;
            Debug.Log(counter);
            if (counter == 1)
            {

                Destroy(sphereBase);
                Destroy(capsule);
                sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(255, 0, 0); //color
            }

            if (counter == 2)
            {
                Destroy(sphere);
                cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 255, 0);
            }

            if (counter == 3)
            {
                Destroy(cube);
                capsule = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
                capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 25, 230);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want your sphere to morph into a cube? thats not a simple project, if you just want to swap it, sure..  Your question doesnt seem to tie in with the the title though, please review your question and make it clearer exactly what you are asking

Comment: What does happen when you execute that project? Also ensure that the newly created primitives are at the right position by setting their transform.position

Comment: @AlexGeorg When i execute the project, the code create a sphere, when i click the screen, my counter encreases and the sphere is destroyed and the cube is created. But i need to use the rigid body for those objects and if i set the rigidbody in the **EmptyGameObject** the 3dobject that the code create don't have the rigidbody...

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry for my bad english... Yes, i'd like to morph the sphere into a cube.

Comment: Fear you have to add the rigid body component with the script as well because primitives have no rigid body. Also be sure you know what BugFinder refers to by morphing: He means animating that the sphere gradually turns more and more into the shape of a cube.

Comment: @upstagesum morphing so that one becomes another is not a simple task, if you are just swapping it that is easy enough as you can have as many child objects with the relevant shapes on and just switch in and out as required

Comment: Thanks guys. the sphere that i created, will run on x asix. When i click on the screen the sphere will become a cube with the same x asix position. @AlexGeorg ah sorry for mistake :). no no i don't need to gradually switch from the primitives, i need a fast switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to initialise the objects in the Start() Method like this and set them inactive like this:

```
Start() {
     sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
     sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(255, 0, 0); //color
     cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
     cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 255, 0);
     capsule = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
     capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 25, 230);

     capsule.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
     capsule.SetActive(false);
     cube.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
     cube.SetActive(false);
     sphere.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
}
```

And just activate the object you need in Update() method like this

```
Update() {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
       counter++;
       Debug.Log(counter);

       switch(counter) {
         case 1:
           sphere.SetActive(true);
           cube.SetActive(false);
           capsule.SetActive(false);
           break;
          case 2:
           sphere.SetActive(false);
           cube.SetActive(true);
           capsule.SetActive(false);
           break;
          case 3:
           sphere.SetActive(false);
           cube.SetActive(false);
           capsule.SetActive(true);
           counter=0;
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Attach this script to an empty GameObject and it should work

To use a rigidbody add in Start()

```
capsule.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
sphere.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Comment: In the Start() method you can also attach a rigidbody to your objects or you can leave it empty and create this hierarchy directly in the Editor

Comment: I have a question, is it possible to use the same RigidBody for all the GameObjects? Because, in this way, when i click on the screen, each object has his RB. For example, if the sphere fall off a plane and i click on the screen, the cube will be generated on the old position of the sphere.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just use gameobject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>(); in Start(). Then the Rigidbody component is on your empty GameObject. I you do this remove the other AddComponent<Rigidbody>() calls.

Comment: Also you should do the setParents calls like this: capsule.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, false); so the objects spawn at the location of your empty GameObject and not at (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Thanks for explication. :)