# Transform Cube to Sphere in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need help in Transforming Cube to Sphere in Unity 3d and Vice versa with timer.
as i tried I've tried to create a Empty Game Object and create this script for change the object, but with the empty object I can't use the Rigidbody for the spawned 3d Objects
can any one help ?

Note : I Followed This Answer and still have Problem
[Unity 3d, sphere transform into cube when I tap on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59930574/unity-3d-sphere-transform-into-cube-when-i-tap-on-screen)

Comment: you mean gradually (from cube to sphere) as an animation or at once?

Comment: Yes gradually (from cube to sphere) as an animation  and also vice versa (from sphere to Cube) with timer

Comment: As a whole unity doesn’t exactly do that out the tin. You would need to manually adjust the mesh to change the shape

Comment: @BugFinder, I think it can but with shaders. It is a complicated thing. You can check out raymarching technique. Check [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3dlfDs).

Comment: with a little bit of effort and googling you can get that to work in unity. However it will be in a quad (2D). Transforming the mesh and the vertices to achieve that same effect with vertices in a 3d scene might be even more epic

Answer (score 0):

the best way with good quality is Morphing and then you can change the frame of animation in run time and the result is gonna be really good.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOn1HXSMMI4